# Python regex to strip html a tags without href attribute

Tags: python, html, regex, strip, htmlcleaner

I'm having a string that has been cleaned with lxml's Cleaner, so all links are now in the form Content. Now I'd like to strip out all links that have no href attribute, e.g.

```
<a rel="nofollow">Link to be removed</a>
```

should become

```
Link to be removed
```

The same for:

```
<a>Other link to be removed</a>
```

Shoudl become:

```
Other link to be removed
```

Simply all links with a missing href attribute. It doesn't have to be regex, but since lxml returns a clean markup structure, it should be possible. What I need, is a source string stripped of such non-functional a tags.

Comment: Don't use regex to read/manipulate HTML. Use an HTML/XML library instead

Comment: Which one does that and how? Can't find this feature in lxml, FilterHTML or bleach. Additionally, the string has already been parsed by lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `drop_tag` method.

```
import lxml.html

root = lxml.html.fromstring('<div>Test <a rel="nofollow">Link to be <b>removed</b></a>. <a href="#">link</a>')
for a in root.xpath('a[not(@href)]'):
    a.drop_tag()

assert lxml.html.tostring(root) == '<div>Test Link to be <b>removed</b>. <a href="#">link</a></div>'
```

http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

> .drop_tag():
>       Drops the tag, but keeps its children and text.

Comment: Thanks!! That works nicely. It works for me if I use this xpath: '//a[not(@href)]'. Without "//" it doesn't find all nested links.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crummy.com%2Fsoftware%2FBeautifulSoup%2F&ei=4-7DUcnQLqf_iAeN44E4&usg=AFQjCNHAxwplurFOBqg5cehWQEVKi-TuLQ&sig2=rx7FMa5HHI3bFjXI-DY-wQ&bvm=bv.48293060,d.aGc), which will make it easier to find `<a>` tags without a `href`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """
... <a rel="nofollow">Link to be removed</a>
... <a href="alink">This should not be included</a>
... <a>Other link to be removed</a>
... """
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> for i in soup.find_all('a', href=False):
...     i.replace_with(i.text)
... 
>>> print soup
<html><body>Link to be removed
<a href="alink">This should not be included</a>
Other link to be removed</body></html>
```

Comment: That outputs the text, but I'd like to strip the html tags only inside the source string. I'll edit my question to clear that up.

Comment: @Nasmon Oh, so something like `Hello. <a>Test</a>. Yay.` should be `Hello. Test. Yay.`?

Comment: Exactly, that would be great!

Comment: Thank you Haidro! Since I'm already using lxml and don't have BeautifulSoup installed, I've accepted falsetru's answer. But it's great to have an alternative with BeautifulSoup!

Comment: @Nasmon That's perfectly fine, no problem :)

Comment: @Nasmon, If `a` tag contain another tags, that will be lost.